# VisualVM can't connect to any PID on Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, jmx, embedded-jetty, visualvm

No matter what I start up, Visual VM just gives me "Unknown Application" and "Not supported for this JVM" on my Mac.

I've tried JBoss, Jetty, Eclipse - just to see if it would be able to identify / profile anything, and so far, nada.

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04-248-10M3025)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01-101, mixed mode)

Running on Snow Leopard. I've tried with the default visual vm (which appears to be 1.0) and a freshly downloaded version from https://visualvm.dev.java.net/download.html .

I also can't seem to get jconsole to connect to anything, and I think the two are related. I am using "-Xshare:off" as recommended to prevent crashing, but I can't connect anyway, so that's moot.

I've also verified that Visual VM and these other apps are running from the same JVM:

VisualVM:
010-03-23 13:35:09
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.3-b01-101 mixed mode):

JBoss:
2010-03-23 13:35:57
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.3-b01-101 mixed mode):

I have no idea what's wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I have an answer, but is there any chance that you have an underscore in your user name?

I see similar problems, and found that there is an old bug in jps that causes problems if you have an underscore in your username. This was fixed in Java 1.6 (by Sun), but I'm not sure it was by Apple. I've found that if I use a user that does not have an underscore in the user name, things work on my Mac. But, with the underscore... well, not so much.

Comment: I think you are/were absolutely right. My username does contain an underscore. I'm now running the latest java 1.6.0_20-b02-279-10M3065 though and I no longer seem to be having the problem.

Comment: Yes. I think the last update Apple pushed for Java resolved the issue. jvisualvm has been working for me (and my underscored username) every since.